# Strange behaviors in adding integers from Python script

Tags: python, scripts, programming

This python script is adding the sums of the numbers entered in a single line delimited by space except that it is not adding correctly. Thanks in advance.

```
Print "Enter Numbers:"
list=raw_input().split()
list=map(int,list)

for result in list:
   result+=result

print result
```

For example:

```
./sum_numbers
Enter Numbers:
1 1 1 1
22

./sum_numbers
Enter Numbers:
1 2 3 4 5 6
12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
print "Enter Numbers:"
list=raw_input().split()
list=map(int,list)

result = 0

for number in list:
   result += number

print result
```

The result is:

```
python sum_num.py
Enter Numbers:
1 2 3 4 5 6
21
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for result in list:
   result+=result
```

Interpretation:

- get first/next item in `list` into `result`
- add `result`to `result` and store it in `result`
- repeat; get next item in `list` into `result` **(note: this discards the result on the previous line)**